# solving large problems in maxima without heap problems

Tags: maxima

A quick search of this site will yield solutions for the dreaded game over message when running large expressions in maxima
These I have found can be mitigated by adding

```
 :lisp (ext:set-limit 'ext:heap-size 1000000000000)
```

to the beginning of the program. However although this increases the size of what maxima can process, it eventually runs into the following

```
Too many heap sections: Increase MAXHINCR or MAX_HEAP_SECTS
```

The machine has plenty of free RAM

how does one do this ?

Comment: I gather that you are working withe SBCL; if that's not the case, maybe you can say so. Anyway, although it is annoying that it's troublesome to configure Maxima to use more memory, I think it's likely that Maxima can't really make use of large amounts of memory, since Maxima using a lot of memory is usually (not always) a consequence of generate enormous expressions, and increasing memory often (not always) means it just churns and grinds away more and more, generating larger and larger expressions until it runs out again.

Comment: Given that, a way forward might be to talk about what specific problem you're working on, and how the expressions involved might be reduced in size. Another approach could be to try to use Maxima with a different Lisp implementation; they seem to vary greatly in how they allocate memory. I seem to recall Clisp is more efficient with memory and GCL is less efficient, although of course YMMV. Finally, to continue using SBCL (or whatever the current implementation), you might need to ask in a forum for that specific implementation.

Comment: Sorry I can't be more helpful. At this point I think the most helpful thing would be to hear about what you are working on. A specific example could be helpful.

Comment: @Robert Dodier I'm generating a sequence of expressions for a series of greens functions. Yes along the way one can reduce the complexity by a series of substitutions, but even so, these do have 1000's of terms in them, but the point of the maxima script is to generate c code. I get a few functions generated by increasing the heap size, but the complete lack of documentation is annoying. Given the thing doesn't have to run very often, it just needs to run at all.

Comment: Okay, got it, that makes sense. Well, I guess at this point my advice is, on the Lisp side, to take up the question of how to increase the available memory. From the message you got before, maybe it's necessary to rebuild Lisp and then rebuild Maxima; just guessing here. On the Maxima side, maybe try to reduce the size of the problems that need to be solved. E.g. if you're working with a sum, then work on the terms one by one. I don't know what's possible there. You will get more and better Maxima-specific advice on the mailing list: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss